# Implementation of s-mac protocol

Tags: networking, ns2, ns-3

I was given a project about S-Mac protocol which i supposed to do in NS-3. 
Well,I have an idea where do i start. 
If any one is familliar with ns3 please give me some advices about that.
Thank you  and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: ns3 Forum : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users

Comment: Start with NS3 [Manual] (https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/index.html)